# How can I access envelope document URL publically using envelope ID in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

I have setup of Powerform using an embedded URL.
After Signing the document, we are saving envelope Id.
But using envelope id, How can I get the envelope document from docusign?

I have check API of get envelops but not able to get it

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this article](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/download-envelope-documents/) that shows how to download documents from DocuSign using the [DocuSign eSignature REST API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/).
You can also use the web-app by constructing a URL that looks like this:

```
https://appdemo.docusign.com/documents/details/{{envelopeID}}
```